# Search box within the detail page for the Job & Candidate modules

Tags: ux-designer

I'm currently in the process of redesigning our product's detail page. We offer an ATS product with both job and candidate modules. Presently, we have global search option in the navigation bar. I'm considering integrating a search function within the detail page. Would this be beneficial for our users? Additionally, I welcome suggestions on how to provide information when conducting a search within the detail page.

Thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Reddit.

They have a search field that's always in the same spot. But if you're in a subreddit (in your case a detail page) then the UI makes it clear you're going to be searching inside that subreddit.

Global: [image]

Detail view: [image]

This keeps things consistent, and users can click the (x) to change their search to global.

Comment: Thanks for your information. ParrotMaster.