# Global search results best practices on a brand asset site

Tags: search, best-practice, search-results

[image]

When users use the global search (whether they're looking for how-to, brand and logo documentation or even a specific asset) they can use the global search. The image is how the results are presented (with tabs for downloads, templates and then site search results). I feel like this is breaking best practice but I'm struggling to articulate why. Is it common/best practice to include site links among assets for download?

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify? I really don't understand the question. However, a search bar with no logo and just floating above the navigation does look odd.

Comment: Whether the user uses the search at the top or the one on this page, it presents assets first before any site links as results (opposite of Google). 

I blocked off the logo which would normally be upper left.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the search above the navigation does create a lot of unused space, and it pushes the navigation down when that is commonly at the very top.

The best place for the search would be where you now have the "People of Action Materials", but you already have that there. You can stretch the navmenu to create space if that still suits the design you want.

An alternative solution is one I actually gave to another answer here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/149895/171338
[image]

This uses the same search box, but lets the user remove the page-specific search to go global. The only problem is that this might not be intuitive to your users.